# Should we request a banner to warn about our policy on AI-generated content?

Tags: discussion, status-review

As announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881), sites are allowed to request a banner that would remind answerers about our policy on AI-generated content. The text would say something like:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Academia.SE. [Learn more](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5225).

Do we want to request such a banner for our site? Personally, I'm inclined to say it couldn't hurt. It will appear only over the Answer box, like this:

[image: AI answer warning banner]

(This is how it appeared on Stack Overflow; for our site it would say Academia Stack Exchange)

Comment: You specify "answers" in the banner; does it mean that AI-generated *questions* are ok?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This particular banner appears specifically on the window where answers are composed https://i.stack.imgur.com/StYoj.png , and I don't think we have a lot of choice about what it says specifically, though we could insist.

Comment: The only hurt involved is a slight reduction in screen real estate. I personally surf SE on my desk machine, where this is really not an issue. I wonder what percentage of a mobile phone screen this banner takes up? That said, have we had enough of an AI deluge here to make such an ad worthwhile?

Comment: @StephanKolassa It only appears with the answer box, I added a picture from the linked Meta post.

Comment: Also note that the Stack Exchange network employee mentioned "All users will see this banner when posting an answer with the option to dismiss. Once dismissed, logged-in users will not see this banner again". See [Network Meta Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera) linked in the question for more info.

Answer (score 8):

I think it is probably fine and is certainly worth emphasizing. The only issue I see, however, is that in the UI for a phone, it separates the formatting bar from the text form. That bar is especially useful, I think, on phones. And there is already a separation possible for the warning to be nice to new users.

I doubt that a UI redesign is in the works.

Answer (score 3):

No real objection, but the way it is expressed is also an effective reminder that it is possible to generate answers by AI. If there is any way to adapt the text, it might make more sense to actually say what is allowed instead of saying what is not.