# Should we request a pop-up to warn users about creating new tags?

Tags: discussion, status-review, tags

Given all the recent discussion about [banners](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/should-we-request-a-banner-to-warn-about-our-policy-on-ai-generated-content?cb=1) and [tags](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5406/specific-tags-for-subfields-desirable), I raise the following question: should we request a warning pop-up whenever someone tries to create a new tag? Apparently this [is possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62591/warning-or-confirmation-on-new-tag-creation/233897#233897) and would look like this.

[image]

I doubt it is possible for each site to request custom wording, but if it is possible, I would request even stronger wording. Perhaps the last paragraph could say:

> Creating a new tag is almost never the right thing to do; most new tags require an approved proposal on [meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There's a lot of activity on meta these days, so I'll assume that upvotes on the question indicate agreement. If anyone disagrees, please post an answer.

Comment: My upvote indicates support for requesting a popup with (at least) the default text. I'm not sure I'd go as far as your suggested stronger statement, however.

Comment: @Anyon, and I'd support the stronger text.

Comment: Since when have tags required a "proposal"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - there was some discussion about it [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5407/79875). A proposal is probably not necessary in every single case, but it's a good rule-of-thumb for newer users.

Comment: AS you can see, I participated there. There's a lot of points in your answer and I guess I would say it's not really a straightforward proposal to require a post on meta before creating a tag.